# How do I properly nest these loops in C?

Tags: c, loops, for-loop

I need to make a program that prints this:

```
.......#
......##
.....###
....####
...#####
..######
.#######
########
```

Basically, if the n is 8. it will print 7 dots and 1 hash***. then in the next row it will print 7 dots and 2 hashes, then 6 dots and 3 hashes until there are 0 dots and 8 hashes.
So far my code looks like this:

```
int main(void)
{
    int G = 1;
    int n = 8;
    int m = 0;
    int k = 0;
    int Z = 1;
    for (m = n; m > 0; m --)
    {
        for (k = n - 1; k >= Z; k --)
        {
            printf(".");
        } 
        printf("\n");
        Z = Z + 1;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i ++)
    {
        
        for (int j = 0; j < G; j++)
        {

            printf("#");
        }
        printf("\n");
        G = G + 1;
    }
}
```

But the result of this comes out as this:

```
.......
......
.....
....
...
..
.

#
##
###
####
#####
######
#######
########
```

Comment: Can you write out the instructions that you want the computer to do on paper? Do you understand what order the computer does the instructions in when there's a loop?

Comment: I have some idea. but I'm really new to programming and I'm not even sure what information to look up in order to solve this. 
it should print 7 dots and 1 hash at the same time and then subract 1 from 7 and add 1 to 1 but I don't know how to do this at the same time.

Comment: Do you understand what order the computer does the instructions in when there's a loop?

Comment: Yes. the inner loop goes first.

Comment: The thing you just said doesn't really make sense. If you put a print inside a loop then the inner print doesn't "go first". So if you put a loop inside a loop then the inner loop doesn't "go first". The loop doesn't care what's inside it, even if that is another loop - they don't interact *at all*.

Answer (score 2):

Since this is obviously homework or some self studies, I'll write how you need to think here.

The first problem is to be able to print ONE row given total number of rows and current row.

So let's start with total number or rows. I will use more descriptive variable names, which you also should.

```
int total = 8;
```

Now we need to print one row, given the current row. Let's assume that the first row has number 1. Let's start with the dots.

```
for(int i=0; i<(total-row); i++)
    printf(".");
```

Then we continue with the hashes:

```
for(int i=0; i<row; i++)
    printf("#");
```

And now we just need to do this `total` times and add a newline after each:

```
for(int row=1; row<total; row++) {
        for(int i=0; i<(total-row); i++)
                printf(".");

        for(int i=0; i<row; i++)
                printf("#");

        printf("\n");
}
```

Please note that it is very common with obo (off by one) errors when doing things like this. We could let 0 be the first row instead of one, but then we need to change a few other things. You said you wanted 1 hash and 7 dots on first line and 8 hash and 0 dots on last line, which seems a bit odd, but just change `row<total` to `row<total+1` and you get that.

Comment: Thank you. It's not a homework. But I am doing a course on programming and this is the first problem. Being that I have no previous experience in any of this I'm kind of stuck and seeing a solution will help me figure out the logic of it, how I should come up with that solution myself.

Comment: @igortadic Yep, glad to help. But just so you know, SO is not really intended for beginner tutoring. It's more like for common specific problems that others can benefit from.

Answer (score 0):

You'll rather want something that does the printing from within the same loop. Here's some pseudo code of a simple way to write this algorithm:

```
for(int dots=n-1; dots>DOTS_MIN; dots--)
{
  for(int i=0; i < dots; i++)
    print dot

  for(int i=dots; i < n; i++)
    print hash

  printf("\n");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First, start from *naming*, it's a challenging task to find out what `Z` stands for.
So we have

```
 int totalRows = 4;
 int totalColumns = 8;
```

and we should print out `totalRows` of rows:

```
 for (int row = 1; row <= totalRows; ++row) {
 }
```

from 2nd row on we should add a *new line*:

```
 for (int row = 1; row <= totalRows; ++row) {
   /* Start a new line from the 2nd row on */    
   if (row > 1)
     printf("\n");    
 }
```

Time to print dots, we have `totalColumns - row` of them:

```
 for (int i = 1; i <= totalColumns - row; ++i)
   printf(".");
```

Followed by `row` `#` symbols:

```
 for (int i = 1; i <= row; ++i)
   printf("#");
```

Combining these chunks all together:

```
int main() {
  int totalRows = 4;
  int totalColumns = 8;

  for (int row = 1; row <= totalRows; ++row) {
    /* Start a new line from the 2nd row on */    
    if (row > 1)
      printf("\n");    
    
    /* Printing dots */    
    for (int i = 1; i <= totalColumns - row; ++i)
      printf(".");

    /* Printing # */
    for (int i = 1; i <= row; ++i)
      printf("#");
  }

  return 0;
}
```